# handling no internet connection with PhoneGap on Android

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to detect whether or not a user has internet connection on their android device. If they don't have internet, I want to be able to show a view that has a button on it that said "retry", like that of the Google Play app store. I was detecting no signal using a native android webview before using the code below, but I'd now like to find a way to do this same thing with PhoneGap. Also, if anybody could provide some sample code on how to re-load the webpage, that would be excellent!

```
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LoadScreen.class);

            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by using the following code:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Consider using `isConnected()` instead, which guarantees that the network is fully usable. More specifically, the official Android Training on [Managing Network Usage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html#check-connection) says: "You should always check `isConnected()` before performing network operations, since `isConnected()` handles cases like flaky mobile networks, airplane mode, and restricted background data."

Answer (score 0):

You can test the `navigator.online` value to determine connectivity:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.onLine

Comment: so your saying create a javascriptinterface? Is there a way to do this without having to embed javascript in Java? I've been told that this can cause serious security holes...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've only used phonegap once, and it was primarily HTML/js, with a little native code sprinkled in (but it was iOS, no comment on the java/js combo)