# Display alert message when there's no internet connectivity

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

So I've built an android app using phonegap build. It is a simple app that displays a mobile optimized page within the web view.

This is the code that does the redirect from index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = 'http://app.website.com/';
</script>
```

All I need to do is to display a message within a popup when there's no internet connectivity. Does phonegap provide any such functionality ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [handling no internet connection with PhoneGap on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805823/handling-no-internet-connection-with-phonegap-on-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alert box when no internet connection - Phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009596/alert-box-when-no-internet-connection-phonegap)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `connection` object, documented at:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_connection_connection.md.html